# VLC opens home folder when manually adding subtitles

Tags: 18.04, vlc, subtitle

When I try to manually add subtitles to a video on VLC using the Add subtitle file option, VLC opens my home folder to load the subtitles from, instead of opening the folder where the video is located:

[image: Screenshot while loading subtitlefile]

So how do I make it so that instead of the home folder the folder where the video is located opens up?
BTW I am using 18.04 LTS if it helps.

Comment: That's how the file chooser works in Gnome, so nothing for you to do except maybe try another Ubuntu flavor that isn't gnome based.

Comment: @doug I'm not sure 'bout that. In my 17.10 setup both VLC and SMPlayer open the parent folder of the video file in file chooser while adding subtitles.

Comment: @pomsky I agree, While I was using 17.10 VLC did indeed open the parent folder.

Comment: The poster is using 18.04, the wanted behavior occurred prior to 18.04 but no longer.

Comment: @doug Just checked it in my 18.04 installation, same behaviour as OP with my VLC (installed via `apt`). **But** SMPlayer does open the parent folder. So I guess it has something to do with VLC itself, *not* an issue with file chooser per se.